# Use MultipleChoiceField for class

Tags: django, forms

I want to use multipleChoiceField, to choice from model

I have model,`Template` so ,I did this in forms.py

```
class WorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    templates = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        Template.objects.all(), required=False,  label='template')
```

However it shows error

```
    templates = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am checking the document here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/

However there are only this, not mentioned about using class instance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField), and probably it is better to work with a *named* parameter:

```
class WorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    templates = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Template.objects.all(), required=False,  label='template'
    )
```